# Find lines where fields in specific columns are repeated

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file

```
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC     2          CC       2       CC
```

I wanna print lines where cols `$4,$6,$8,$10,$12,$14,$16,$18,$20,$22,$24` are the same.
So that the output is

```
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC     2          CC       2       CC
```

I'm currently using

```
awk 'n=x[$4,$6,$8,$10,$12,$14,$16,$18,$20,$22,$24]{print n"\n"$0;} {x[$4,$6,$8,$10,$12,$14,$16,$18,$20,$22,$24]=$0;}'
```

But it doesn't it's not working, as I'm ending up with a file double the size of the original input.

Comment: Couldn't you come up with an example where 3 out of 5 or so columns have to have the same value instead of 11 out of 30 or however many that is? Please post [mcve]s, emphasis on ""minimal** to make it as easy as possible for as many people as possible to help you.

Comment: Yeah it would be every other column starting from 4 to 24.

Comment: I understand that, my point is that the example you provide doesn't have to be that lengthy to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your particular requirements all you need is:

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{for (i=6; i<=24; i+=2) if ($i != $4) next} 1' file
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC     2          CC       2       CC
```

Otherwise, for a more general solution, something like this (untested) is IMHO the best approach:

```
awk -F '\t' '
    BEGIN { split("4 6 8",flds) }
    { for (i in flds) if ( $(flds[i]) != $(flds[1]) ) next }
1' file
```

Add other field numbers to the first arg to split() as you like.

It's trivial to specify the field numbers you want to compare and, since it's using literal strings comparisons, that will work with fields of random lengths, fields containing regexp metachars, empty fields, etc., etc.

Comment: I want to check if every other field from 4 to 24 are identical strings. I did split("4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24",tmp), but the output comes back identical to input.

Comment: Then I guess those fields are identical in every line of your input. If you edit your question to provide a minimal example as I suggested earlier then I'll take a look.

Comment: The first approach works great! Thxs. I'll edit to shorter and still complete examples.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep it simple as:

```
awk -F '\t' '$4==$6 && $6==$8 && $8==$10 && $10==$12 && $12==$14 \
&& $14==$16 && $16==$18 && $18==$20 && $20==$22 && $22==$24' file
```

```
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT
NC_044998.1 4017    2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk and a regex. Concatenate all desired columns to a string and check with a regex whether the string from the first desired column occurs exclusively repeatedly.

```
awk '{x=$4$6$8$10$12$14$16$18$20$12$14; regex="^(" $4 ")+$"; if(x ~ regex){print}}' file
```

Output:

```
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT     0          TT       0       TT
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC     2          CC       2       CC
```

Comment: My first approach was going to be this one but I ditched it later as there can be some special regex meta characters in column 4 and building a regex might throw an unexpected error.

Comment: It'd also fail if a field were empty or if the fields could be of differing lengths from each other but it looks like the OP always just has 2 alphabetic chars in their input so probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Yes, the points raised should be taken into account before use.

Comment: Yeah the two give indeed different outputs.